# Does a given rect intersect a rotated view?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have an NSView that is rotated using -setFrameRotation. (This is necessary because the view responds to mouse events, and you don't get correct behavior if you merely draw the view with a rotated NSAffineTransform.)

Given a rect in the rotated view's superview coordinates, how can I determine what portion of the rect intersects the rotated view's frame?

Use case: the Cocoa text system proposes to draw text in a line fragment rectangle. I need to determine how much of that rectangle may be filled with text without overlapping the rotated view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the point, use an affine transform to rotate into the coordinate system of the bounds of the rect and then rect-test that.